# Laravel "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed" when caching, with Model::where()->get()

Tags: caching, laravel-8

My caching fails with "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed", the fail is on the second part ("news") and not the first ("categories").

I understand that it's a PHP issue, and it's because I use a QueryBuilder, but the `get()` should have solved it, or not?!

(The second query, in the closure, was working before I tried to cache it)
[**edit**]
UsingDB::table('t_news').... works. what is the difference?

```
public function view()
{
    $data_for_view = [
        // this part works
        'categories' => cache()->remember(
            'categories',
            now()->addDays(30),
            function () {
                return Category::all()->where('active', true);
            }
        ),
        // this part fails
        'news' => cache()->remember(
            'last4newsitems',
            now()->addHours(1),
            function () {
                return tNew::where('published', true)->limit(4)->get();
            }
        )];
}
```